# Jwt authorization always giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am a beginner with node js. I want to make an authentication server using jwt (jsonwebtoken).
The problem is when I test my end point "/api/posts?authorisation=Bearer token..." in postman with method POST with the right token, it gives me **forbidden**.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const app = express()

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "Hey there!!!"
    })
})

app.post('/api/posts', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    jwt.verify(req.token, "secretkey", (err, authData) => {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(403) //forbidden
            res.send(`<h2>${err}</h2>`)
        } else {
            res.json({
                message: "Post Created...",
                authData
            })
        }
    })
})

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        id: 1,
        username: "John",
        email: "john@gmail.com"
    }
    jwt.sign({ user: user }, "secretkey", (err, token) => {
        res.json({
            token
        })
    })
})

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"]
    if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
        const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(" ")[1]
        req.token = bearerToken
        next()
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403) //forbidden
    }
}
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running :)")
})
```

I expected it to work because I brought it from a tutorial.

Comment: I'd add extra console logs before both of the sendStatus(403)s to be sure which one you're hitting, and also log out the contents of err in the jwt.verify failure case. Are you getting the <h2>error</h2> response in Postman? What's the error?

Comment: when I test my end point "/api/posts?authorisation=Bearer token..." - oh, that's the problem. No, it's authorization with a 'z' as in your verifyToken() function, and it should be passed as a header not a query string param.

Comment: You are performing twice the jwt validation and passing the authorization as query param when a header is expected. Also there is a typo: Change authorisation to authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works

[image]

#### The problem is in your request invocation:

According to the oauth2 spec, the Authorization token should be a header and your code expect that

[image]

So the token should be sent as http header, not as a query param like `foo/bar?authorization=Bearer token..."`.

Here some samples

**Postman**

[image]

**Axios (javascript)**

```
let webApiUrl = 'example.com/getStuff';
let tokenStr = 'xxyyzz';
axios.get(webApiUrl, 
    { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${tokenStr}` } });
```

#### Advice

- Read about oauth2 and jwt
- Perform the token validation in the middleware to avoid the validation on each route

Comment: Or you could use the Authorization tab in Postman, type Bearer Token.

Comment: ui tools hide the real implementation. In the background  postman  send the Authorization as Header

Comment: Of course, yes, but that's what the Auth tab is there for

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I think my head was off XD.